# Is it possible to run same specflow test again based on outcome?

Tags: c#, testing, specflow

I'm using Specflow, Visual studio 2015 and Nunit. I need if a test fails to run it once again. I have

```
[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario1()
{
    if (Test Failed  and the counter is 1)
    {
        StartTheLastTestOnceAgain();
    }
}
```

How do I start the last test again?

Comment: When you run tests in visual studio you could filter the tests on which failed and run them again. If you want to go more automatic you might want to look into build servers like TFS or TeamCity, for examples. Those have the possibility to have more logic around your tests to run them twice.
There might be a downside to include more code around a test to run them again because then the test changes and gets more complicated.

Comment: This is not what i need. Some tests might fail because of the network issue and that is why i want to re-run those who failed. At the end I'm sending a report and this is why i need this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just capture the failure during the assert step and then retry what ever it is that your testing for. Something like:

```
[Given(@"I'm on the homepage")]
public void GivenImOnTheHomepage()
{
    go to homepage...
}
[When(@"When I click some button")]
public void WhenIClickSomeButton()
{
    click button...
}
[Then(@"Something Special Happens")]
public void ThenSomethingSpecialHappens()
{
    var theRightThingHappened = someWayToTellTheRightThingHappened();
    var result = Assert.IsTrue(theRightThingHappened);
    if(!result)
    {
       thenTrySomeStepsAgainHere and recheck result using another assert
    }
}
```

Comment: not in my case, I have more than 2000 tests and only on few places I have   Assert.IsTrue or Assert.Equals

Comment: Doesn't throw Assert.IsTrue an exception? How is the if ever executed?

Answer (score 2):

In NUnit there is the RetryAttribute (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Retry-Attribute) for that. It looks like that the SpecFlow.Retry plugin is using that (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Retry/). This plugin is a 3rd party plugin and I did not used it yet. So no guarantee that this works as you want.

As alternative you could use the SpecFlow+Runner (http://www.specflow.org/plus/). This specialized runner has the option to rerun your failed test. (http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Execution - retryFor/retryCount config value).

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+.

Comment: I have added Specflow.Retry but after installing it most probably something was uninstalled so I had to revert back. I'm going to try with NUnit retry

Comment: I wasn't able to rerun tests with SpecFlow.Retry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586334/rerun-failed-tests-using-specflow-retry