# Rerun failed tests using Specflow.Retry

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I'm trying to rerun failed tests in specflow using specflow.retry plugin https://github.com/DamirAinullin/specflow-retry
[image]

Here is my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <unitTestProvider name="nUnit" />
    <plugins>
        <add name="SpecFlow.Retry.Generator" path="..\packages\SpecFlow.Retry.2.4.0\lib\net45" type="Generator" />
    </plugins>
</configuration>
```

I'd appreciate any help if someone gives a hint what's wrong from my side

Here is a few warning that i get on building the project:

```
: warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: SpecFlow.CustomPlugin 2.4.0 requires SpecFlow (= 2.4.0) but version SpecFlow 3.3.74 was resolved.
warning NU1701: Package 'FluentAssert 1.0.0.11' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
: warning NU1701: Package 'SpecFlow.Retry 2.4.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2081,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\magick.net-q16-x64\7.21.1\lib\netstandard20\Magick.NET-Q16-x64.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
: warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://www.specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/'
: warning CS0618: 'ScenarioContext.Current' is obsolete: 'Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection - https://www.specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/'
>Done building project "TestAutomation.UI.Tests.csproj".
=
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? We know the expected behavior (tests get retried) but what is the actual behavior you are observing?

Comment: The retry is not applied once test fails. It's executed only one time. Scenario is marked with the tag @retry though

Comment: Which version of .NET is your project targeting? I see yellow triangle icons next to some of the NuGet packages in your screenshot. This makes me wonder if this is a compatibility issue.

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Do you get any warnings when building the solution? If so, please add those to your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, updated the question with a list of warnings

Comment: It looks like you need to upgrade or remove NuGet packages that are not compatible with .NET Core.

Comment: But SpecFlow.Retry 2.4.0 nuget package is the latest available version

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow.Retry only supports SpecFlow 2.*.
You can't use it with SpecFlow 3. We changed a lot in the plugin infrastructure from 2 to 3.

It looks like the plugin isn't maintained anymore, as the latest change was done more than 2 years ago.

If you want to switch unit test runner, you could switch to the SpecFlow+ Runner which has a retry feature build in. Documentation at https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Profile/Execution.html

---

Full Disclosure: I am the Community Manager of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @Andreas